# Lost power during update and now i cannot install any packages or even update/repair update

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies

I lost power during and update and now i cannot install or update any packages. I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 32bit. on terminal I get this message:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.13.0-29 (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic:
linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic depends on linux-headers-3.13.0-29; however:
Package linux-headers-3.13.0-29 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic; however:
Package linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.

linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.13.0.29.35); however:
Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried configuring it and installing the dependencies but so far not luck.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install -3.13.0-29-generic
```